# xpatch bug in texlive 2019?

Tags: nomencl, xpatch

I am running the slightly modified [example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279746/remove-title-in-nomenclature) with pdflatex and then makeindex (makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o myfile.nls myfile.nlo)

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{nomencl} 

\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\section*{\nomname}}{\relax}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}

\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}
text
\nomenclature[1]{$\mu$}{variable}
\printnomenclature[0.9in]
\end{document}
```

However, the section title `Nomenclature` is still there while it should not. The compilation also outputs `success` so I am lost. Is this a bug in the `xpatch` package?

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [xpatch bug in texlive 2019?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/562044/xpatch-bug-in-texlive-2019)

Comment: @Mico I've deleted the other one. I do not know what happened..

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Not me. I have no clue why. I see this "xpatch.sty 2012/10/02 v0.3 Extending etoolbox patching commands". Not good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nomencl` package has been updated recently and now it uses by default the `tocbasic` package.

In order to use the old method, you need to call the package with the option `notocbasic`.

```latex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: nomencl
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage[notocbasic]{nomencl} 

\patchcmd{\thenomenclature}{\section*{\nomname}}{\relax}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Failure}}
\makenomenclature 

\begin{document}
text
\nomenclature[1]{$\mu$}{variable}
\printnomenclature[0.9in]
\end{document}
```

[image]

With the `tocbasic` method, you have to patch `\tocbasic@listhead`, but this might have adverse effects on other parts of the document.

```latex
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\usepackage{nomencl}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd\tocbasic@listhead{\section*}{\@gobble}{}{}
\makeatother

\makenomenclature

\begin{document}
text
\nomenclature[1]{$\mu$}{variable}
\printnomenclature[0.9in]
\end{document}
```

Comment: ah ok done! Why is my `xpatch` package from 2012 though?

Comment: And is there a new method achieving the same result? (removing the section title)